# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : at url:
  I am trying to call controller insert/getdata

```
<script>
$(window).load(function(){
    // do something 
$(document).ready(function () {

                //d=   <?php echo $userid; ?>
                $.ajax({   
                    url:"http://localhost/CodeIgniter/index.php/insert/getdata", //The url where the server req would we 
                    async: false,
                    type: "POST", //The type which you want to use: GET/POST
                   data: {activeNodeID : <?php echo $userid; ?>}, //The variables which are going.

                    //This is the function which will be called if ajax call is successful.
                    success: function(response){

                    $("#ques").html(response);
                    $("#ques").show();
                }
                });


        });
```

});

Comment: is this a piece of your PHP script?

Comment: no it is in View and i am trying to load script as the page is loaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That line is fine. I think the error is being raised because of this line:

```
<?php echo @userid; ?>
```

This code should be placed inside a PHP server script, but found its way to the browser which does not understand it. Replace that code with something appropriate (a variable or a constant string literal) and it will work

Comment: just i commented that line as i dont want to pass any data